# From title case to sentence case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write a helper to translate a string from `"something_like_this"` to `"Something like this"`. I'm using `"something_like_this".titlecase` to get it to `"Something Like This"` but I'm stuck lowercasing every uppercase letter except the first.

I suppose I'm looking for something like this:

```
def write_sentence
  string.titlecase.gsub!(/UPPERCASE-TO-LOWERCASE-EXCEPT-FIRST/)
  #that should be something to lowercase everything except the first letter
  return string
end
```

So in the view I could just write `string.write_sentence` and have it return exactly what I want. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I should mention that the string can sometimes be just one word, in which case the string should be converted from `"something"` to `"Something"`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this,

```
"something_like_this".humanize
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize

Answer (score 2):

You can just use **`capitalize`**

```
greeting = 'HELLO, WORLD!'
puts greeting.capitalize
> Hello, world!
```

Answer (score -2):

Easiest solution would probably be to just grab the first letter, uppercase it, and then put it together with a new string where the first letter has already been removed. Then just running a normal replace to change `_` into . No need for any fancy regex here.